# Simple CRUD tutorial about Play Framework and MySQL using Ebean?

Tags: java, mysql, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I am new to Play Framework. I have started learning it and so far I am enjoying it. 
I have started to learn Play Java.

I have my controller and model set up as follow:

**Controller:**

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

//Import Product model
import models.Product;

public class Products extends Controller{


    /**
     * List all Products
     */
    public static Result list(){
        Object allProducts = Product.findAll();
        return ok((Content) allProducts); //return all products
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
package models;

import java.util.List;
import play.db.*;

import play.api.db.DB;

import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import com.avaje.ebean.Query;

public class Product {

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String description;

    public Product(){

    }

    public Product(int id, String name, String description){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public static  String findAll(){
        //Using ebean and MySql, fech the product table
        //and return all products
    }
}
```

To enable the use of MySql, I have already edited the /conf/application.conf as follow:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/play_db?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=user 
db.default.password=pass
ebean.default="models.*"
```

I have a play_db database with one table shown as follow:

[image]

My problem is how to fetch all the products in the Product model using ebean and MySQL. 
Can someone please point me to a simple crud tutorial which uses play java in combination with ebean and MySql? Thanks

Anyone?

**NOTE**
By the way, I am using Play v.2.3.5 for Java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hooray!!!

**List action**

```
public static Result list(){
    List<Product> products = Product.findAll();
    return ok(play.libs.Json.toJson(products));
}
```

**findAll method in Product Model**

```
public static  List<Product> findAll(){
    return  Product.find.orderBy("id").findList();  
}
```

Lastly, I have to enable evolution in /conf/application.conf by uncommenting the following line

```
# evolutionplugin=disabled
```

Add **@Entity** just before **public class Product extends Model{**

**Final code:**

```
package models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import play.db.*;
import play.db.ebean.Model;

import play.api.db.DB;

import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import com.avaje.ebean.Query;


@Entity

public class Product extends Model{

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String description;

    public static Model.Finder<String, Product> find = new Model.Finder<String, Product>(String.class, Product.class);

    public Product(){

    }

    public Product(int id, String name, String description){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public static  List<Product> findAll(){
        return  Product.find.orderBy("id").findList();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help anyone who is also new to Play Java