# Unable to connect to MySQL and perform operations in Play Framework 2.4

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, crud

I am very new to Play and Java (i come from a Python and Django background :) ). I am trying to connect to MYSQL database and read values from it. However, after trying for about few frustrating hours i am unable to do so. Please Help.

My build.sbt has the dependency added:

```
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
```

My Application.conf file is as (the relevant section)

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/myDBName"
db.default.user="root"
db.default.password="myPassword"
```

And i am trying to read the values from Db on application start. Later i would also want to do it from any action in the controller. The relevant section of my code:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import play.db.*;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Override
public void onStart(play.Application appConfig){
DataSource dataSources = DB.getDataSource();
java.sql.Connection connectionSQL =  DB.getConnection();
ResultSet rs = connectionSQL.prepareStatement("select * from mytable").executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) {
      System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
      Logger.debug(rs.getString(1));
     }
}
```

However i am getting a null pointer exception. I also tried many other SO questions such as [Simple CRUD tutorial about Play Framework and MySQL using Ebean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327664/simple-crud-tutorial-about-play-framework-and-mysql-using-ebean) but they are all for previous versions. Also,the official [Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDatabase) seems lacking in this regard. I understand it being a relatively new and open source project but that's just my two cents. If i am able to do this, i would try to publish an official tutorial for lost souls like me. Till then, please help me.
Thanks

**EDIT1** @biesior Sorry for missing out these details....Have added in the question now. Also.

1. I do not have models yet.
2. I may require in future but not now.
3. Currently i just want to access existing tables.

Just as a side note i was able to create models and access MongoDB using Morphia object and perform operations. So i have the basic idea ***but as of now i just need to access existing MySQL db with play java***

Comment: 1. Have you got models created for your tables, 2. do you want to use models? 3. is this new project or accessing existing table(s)?

Comment: @biesior Sorry for missing out these details....Have added in the question now. Also. I do not have models yet. I may reuire in future but not now. And i just want to access existing tables. Just as a side note i was able to create models and access MongoDB using Morphia object. So i have the basic idea but as of now i just need to access existing MySQL db with play java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well with Java I'd recommend [Ebean's SqlQuery API](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/SqlQuery.html) for doing this (maybe because I just prefer it ;)).

In **project/plugins.sbt** uncomment the line (last one):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

In **built.sbt** modify line and add the **PlayEbean** to enabled plugins, like:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

In your **conf/application.conf** add this line after DB configs:

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

So you can use it i.e. in your action as (sample ofc):

```
    SqlQuery query = Ebean.createSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE :username");
    query.setParameter("username", "%200ok%");

    List<SqlRow> rows = query.findList();

    for (SqlRow row : rows) {
        play.Logger.debug("Found user: " + row.getString("username") + " with ID: " + row.getInteger("id"));
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm...So simple...Thanks a lot...Two small questions: 1. Do we not need to close any connections? Is this handled automatically by Ebean. 2. Can you please point me towards some good tutorials for Play2.4 with Java. Once again thanks a ton

Comment: ad 1.You don't need to open/close connections Ebean does it itself. ad 2. Take a look into official docs and tutorials on Play's page. Also get familiar with Activator templates/samples i.e. _Computer Database Java_

Comment: Thank you...will do ASAP